# Why is data getting stored with type as SET in Redis when using Jedis with Spring Data @RedisHash annotation?

Tags: redis, spring-data, jedis, spring-data-redis

I am using spring data redis and and saving my data in the form of hash using the annotation `@RedisHash("myKey")` to my entity class. The data is getting inserted but when I see the type of the data I have inserted it shows SET.
I tried following command :

```
TYPE myKey
```

> Result : set

what changes do I have to make if I want to change type of the data to be saved in hash and not in set ?

This is the defination I get from that annotation :

> RedisHash marks Objects as aggregate roots to be stored in a
>   Redis hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [Hash mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.hashmappers.root) as described in the documentation